# Anyone else experiencing outage on 9/29

Tags: support

Anyone experiencing an outage of the main site?

Comment: Intermittently, yes.

Comment: Me too. Nothing on https://twitter.com/StackStatus or http://stackstatus.net/ yet, though. This already has a couple of dupes, so clearly quite a few people are having issues.

Comment: Wow my *Hackers* reference comment got deleted? Tough crowd tonight.

Comment: It's working for me now

Comment: Has been slow on and off all morning, but yes, now intermittent errors between Cloudfare and SO.

Comment: Zuckerberg not the only one with uptime issues.

Comment: Someone on [twitter](https://twitter.com/Panchiveloz/status/648808061931491328) suggested they're doing their name changes tonight.

Comment: I am seeing this while trying to hit Stack Exchange: http://imgur.com/isNRuwB

Comment: @xDaevax i saw that when i posted this when visiting the main site.

Comment: Error 521, I don't see that very often.

Comment: Wasn't able to log in for the past 2 days. Finally started working a few hours ago.

Comment: Sounds like a DDoS attack to me.

Comment: Not an outage per se, but I'm experiencing extended loading times in review queues.

Answer (score 6):

Best way to stay current on these sort of things is to follow https://twitter.com/StackStatus

We were having problems with Cloudflare and their railgun accelerator. We have turned railgun off and we don't see continued signs of issues. We have opened a support ticket with cloudflare.

Comment: I was experiencing the connectivity issues today waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay before anything appeared on StackStatus. I find that unless it is a planned outage, almost any other venue (even a local bar, no kidding!) will tell me faster whether it's just me or SO is really having problems.

Comment: A public status dashboard is on or to-do, probably early 2016. We got an alert for this, but it needs to be changed to escalate to wake us up

Comment: Then again, Cloudflare will probably kill that dashboard too :)

Comment: Is China at it again? :-) http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-34379254